# isearch with invisible text properties, not overlays?

Tags: isearch, text-properties, visibility

**Q:** how can I get `isearch` to understand invisible text
properties, not just overlays?

I'm writing a major mode that uses text properties rather than
overlays to toggle visibility.  I'd like to use `isearch` to be
able to find invisible text and make it visible, but don't know
how to convince `isearch` to do so.

As an example, evaluate the following function in a buffer:

```
(defun try-me ()
  (let ((text (concat (propertize "Visible text" 'invisible nil)
                      (propertize "\nOtters" 'invisible t))))
    (insert text)))
```

It will insert one line of visible text "Visible text", and
another line of invisible text "Otters" below it.

Using `isearch` to search for "Otters" results in no hits.

How can I get `isearch` a) to find text with the invisible text
property, and b) get it to toggle the invisible text property so
it's visible?  (I imagine I'll need a custom function to do that,
but don't know how to get `isearch` to use that function.)

Comment: By the way, related bug: [Bug#16493 - (setq search-invisible t) is useless, let's allow to turn visible-mode temporarily on](https://debbugs.gnu.org/16493)

Comment: Actually, Isearch does understand and respect text that is made invisible using text properties. Trying to search for matches in invisible text will not find them - the text is *invisible* to searching. I think what you want to ask is how to get Isearch to *open* invisible text, that is, to *find* matches in invisible text, rendering it temporarily visible. That, at that alone, is what Isearch does not do wrt text made invisible by text property instead of overlay. It does not respect an `open` value of `search-invisible` when the text is made invisible using text properties.